Help identifying insect, possibly a carpet beetle larva?
I found this bug on my kids mattress when changing the bedding this morning, sorry I didn't include a scale, I would say it is probably about 1 - 1.5mm in length. It seems to have 6 legs and what looks like 12 "segments" for lack of a better word. Underneath it is soft and a little hairy, it has no hairs on the top of its body but you can see from the photo it has them on its rear and front. It doesn't move very fast.
From what I can tell it is a carpet beetle larva, am I correct? If so, is this is an issue regarding destruction of fabrics? I've not seen another one so would assume probably not, but worth asking. Cheers!


Whilst I don't have an answer for you, there's a related post which may inform you. The comments have a number of interesting links. (Carpet beetle larva would seem probable here).

It does seem likely that this is indeed a carpet beetle larva.
Similar to carpet moths, they cause damage by feeding on organic matter (especially keratin, with wool being one of the key targets) during their larval stage (but not in adult forms). They like darker undisturbed areas and particularly enjoy fabrics that have been worn (as they contain extra seasonings of other organic deposits from human wear).
One swallow does not make a summer and you might not necessarily have an infestation. However, seeing one of these should prompt a very careful inspection of your belongings (especially any precious items composed of wool, silk, feathers or leather) and careful vacuuming of the house, focusing on easily neglected inaccessible corners, crevices etc.
If you have any particularly valuable items (and suspect they might have been infested), freezing the suspected item can be effective. Otherwise, the most robust method of preventing damage is ensuring all clothing is washed soon after wear and stored in air-tight containers (e.g. vacuum packs).
Depending on the scale of the problem, you might want to employ these simple measures, use some simple anti-beetle items (although I do not know enough about their efficacy, beetle traps can also be helpful for monitoring the situation) or even consult a local pest control company...
Good luck!
